# Multiple input using Eval() in Python

Tags: python

Can we use eval() to get multiple data ?

Can we get three data like : `a , b , c = map(float , float(input().split(' '))`
But i want these data are different by using eval()

Comment: Why are you calling `float` twice? Only the first one with map works, the other will error since you are calling it on a list

Comment: Did you mean `a, b, c = map(float, input().split(' '))`? (You can't apply `float` to a list of strings.) `eval` may *seem* simpler, but that's because it will do far more than you intended if your input isn't exactly what you expect. It's better to be explicit about what you want, which limits what can go wrong if you get unexpected input.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as follow, Just remove `float` from `float(input().split(' ')`

```py
a, b, c = map(float , input().split(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an assignment operator inside an eval, meaning you can't use eval to assign variables.

However as others have mentioned, `a, b, c = map(float, input().split(' '))` will prompt the user to input values for a, b, & c.